# How can I find out list of ip address establishing contact to my EC2 port 80 which is behind a load balancer?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I am trying to find the IP addresses that are establishing connection with my EC2 instance behind a load balancer. When I use `netstat -tn 2>/dev/null` it only provides me the load balancer IP address.

Answer (score 1):

With `netstat` you will only ever see the ALB/ELB addresses. To get the client addresses you can either:

1. Enable **Access Logs** on your load balancer:

   - [Access Logs for Your *Application Load Balancer*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) (ALB)
   - [Access Logs for Your *Classic Load Balancer*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html) (ELB)
2. Or inspect and log the HTTP Header **[X-Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)** on your instance. This header contains the original client IP address as visible by the load balancer.

Hope that helps :)